# How to show $\log(\frac{1}{1-t}) \leq t^2 + t$ for $t \in [0,1/2]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

As the title says, according to wolfram alpha this should be true. How can this be shown quickly? Using Taylor expansion  $$\log\frac{1}{1-t} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n}$$
this boils down to showing that for $t \in [0,1/2]$ we have $$\frac{t^2}{2} \geq \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n}$$
How to proceed?

Comment: As in the answer below, if you have an inequality where you can turn it into a differentiable function,    that's a common approach to try

Comment: @Alan More specifically, two natural choices to prove $f(t) \geq g(t)$: (1) study the function $\Delta(t) := f(t)-g(t)$ and show $\Delta(t) \geq 0$. (2) Study the function $R(t) := \frac{f(t)}{g(t)}$ and show $R(t)\geq 1$ (assuming $f,g>0$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to show that  $f\colon[0,1/2]\to\mathbb{R}$
$$
f(t) = t+t^2 + \log(1-t)
$$
is nonnegative. Note that $f$ is differentiable, with $f(0)=0$, and
$$
f'(t) = 1+2t-\frac{1}{1-t} = \frac{t(1-2t)}{1-t} \geq 0
$$
(the last part using $0 \leq t\leq 1/2$) which lets you conclude: $f(t) \geq f(0) = 0$ for all $t\in[0,1/2]$.

Here is a plot of $f$, to help visualise it. [image]

Comment: Nice answer, I like it (+1).